# css Table-layout

Tags: html, css

Why is content in the table appears to start from the center.How to make it to start from where the row starts

```
 <table style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%;" border="1"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="main_table" id="main_table">

   <tr>
                    <td width="20%" height="70px" align="center" id="plugins" class="step step1 clickable" step="1" onclick="javascript:getresource('1','0');">
                       <font color="blue">Plugins</font>
                    </td>
                       <td rowspan="5" width="80%" height="100%" align="center" ><br>
                          <div id="status" class="msg" style="display:none"><br></div>
                          <div id="header_msg" height="100%" align="center"></div>
                          <div id="contents" height="100%"></div>
                          </td>
                  </tr>

 </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove 'align="center"' from both td's and the 2nd div, and if you want the data to start at the top of the cell, add 'valign="top"' to the tr ie:

```
    <table style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%;" border="1"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="main_table" id="main_table">

   <tr valign="top">
                    <td width="20%" height="70px" id="plugins" class="step step1 clickable" step="1" onclick="javascript:getresource('1','0');">
                       <font color="blue">Plugins</font>
                    </td>
                       <td rowspan="5" width="80%" height="100%"><br>
                          <div id="status" class="msg" style="display:none"><br></div>
                          <div id="header_msg" height="100%"></div>
                          <div id="contents" height="100%"></div>
                          </td>
                  </tr>

 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the bloated use of inline CSS, HTML tables for layouts and the not-so-popular -tag, I'd guess it's the..

```
align="center"
```

..that centers your content. Try replacing it with "left" instead. Do consider doing it the CSS way though:

```
text-align: left;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [vertical-align:top](http://w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)